# How to cache KDE main menu in memory?

Tags: kde

When I click main menu button in Windows, it loads instantly. When I click K menu, it loads with a small delay. Seems, that it's loading data from disk. How to make it cache the favorites in memory?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not the desktop effects and window animations causing the delay? And try to see if it is really disk I/O using ``iotop`` or ``iostat``. I'm using KDE and not experiencing any delay in opening it with a lot more entries in Favorites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem go to System settings -> Desktop effects

and uncheck Sliding popups animation